# Django - Setting a value of Model inside template page

Tags: django-models, django-templates

I have a simple Django App having database interactions. I need to make the functionality of Video Visiting counter. So that I need to update- increment the counter each time when user visit the video.

I have a video object on template page(**video-details.html**).
This is how I access the video_file_name.

```
<h1 id="video1">{{video_obj.video_file_name}}</h1>
```

I have video model as:

```
class Video_Mapping(models.Model):
   video_file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   video_description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='Video Description') 
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   video_category_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
   video_seen_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**I want to update the video_seen_count  model value on template page.**

More info: As I can do similar thing in View like following.

> video = Video_Mapping.objects.get(pk=video_id);
>   video.video_description = description; video.save();

Please suggest me the best way to do it in the video-detail.html template page.

Comment: Do you want to increment as a result of user interaction with the page, e.g. pressing a play button? You'll need to make a server call using Javascript.

Comment: @birophilo Currently I just want to increment this based on page visit.

Comment: So just do video.video_screen_count += 1 in your view and video.save()

Comment: @birophilo  Actually I was planning to do something on Template page. But yes I have done this in view as a last option. thanks. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing which I have done here is as per @birophilo'suggestion.
I was actually finding the way to increment the `video_seen_count` value from template(html page).

But after doing more research and try as suggested in comment, I decided to make this increment operation before the template renders(So in the view).

So it worked like:

> video.video_screen_count += 1
>   video.save();

Thanks.